# In fasterxml's JsonParser I want to get the raw text from property

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonparser, fasterxml

I have a sample snippet that parses the JSON that I am trying to get the rawtext of the value.  I want to properly escape the text for XML.

```java
package org.example;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken;

import java.io.IOException;

public class App
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        JsonFactory factory = createJsonFactory(true);
        try (final JsonParser parser = factory.createParser("{ \"value\": \"\\u0000\" }")) {
            JsonToken token;
            while ((token = parser.nextValue()) != null) {
                switch (token) {
                    case VALUE_STRING:
                        String text = parser.getText();
                        System.out.println(text);
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static JsonFactory createJsonFactory(boolean liberal) {
        JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
        factory.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS, true);

        // duplicates are handled in readValue
        factory.configure(JsonParser.Feature.STRICT_DUPLICATE_DETECTION, false);
        if (liberal) {
            factory.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_COMMENTS, true);
            factory.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES, true);
            factory.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_NUMERIC_LEADING_ZEROS, true);
            factory.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);
            factory.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_BACKSLASH_ESCAPING_ANY_CHARACTER, true);
        }
        return factory;
    }
}
```

How do I get the output of `\u0000` instead of the null character?

I have the following as my dependency:

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.13.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use

```
"{ \"value\": \"\\\\u0000\" }"
```

In other words, double up the backslashes.

If you use `\\0000` in your Java string literal, then Java will know that you do not have a Unicode escape sequence (you do not want `\U0000` to be interpreted as the null character).

But that means Java will pass `\u0000` to the JSON parser.

The parser will then apply JSON's own rules regarding backslashes - which also act as escape characters. So, JSON will now interpret `\u0000` as the null character.

By doubling up the backslashes from 2 to 4, you will ensure that JSON receives a string containing `\\u0000`. Java will reduce each pair of backslashes to a single literal backslash in its resulting string.

And that means that JSON will know it is a literal `\u0000` string and not the null character.

Comment: The problem with this is that it does not help with the fn:json-to-xml() XQuery method that should render `<fn:string escaped="true">\u0000</fn:string>`. I created this example to allow for the recreation, but the code is deeper.  Take a look at https://github.com/eXist-db/exist/blob/develop/exist-core/src/main/java/org/exist/xquery/functions/fn/JSON.java where I am working on this.  Also see https://github.com/eXist-db/exist/issues/3594